# Google Sheets - Import Range within a Query

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

Trying to run a query with an import range function built into it, but I keep getting an ERROR message. 
Here is the formula I am trying to use: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1BJ11UiLyiK3PaS2iwHEsyuMMXomdvrEkYYj_Z7bWWw4","Sheet1!A:C"),"Select Col2 where Col1 = '"A1"' ")

I've tested the import range formula without the query and that goes through successfully so it must be something with how I am writing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add **ampersands** (&).  Try this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1BJ11UiLyiK3PaS2iwHEsyuMMXomdvrEkYYj_Z7bWWw4","Sheet1!A:C"),"Select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A1&"' ")
```

Cheers.