# Using query, Import Range and named range to either label the named range or ignore the header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, named-ranges

**Context**

So I am trying to put together some data to run a machine learning model. I need all the data in one google sheet. But I am importing the data from a different spreadsheet saved elsewhere.

This is my current formula
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link", "AvevaReturns")) Screen reader support enabled.`

It returns the spreadsheet but with the column label which is located in row 3 (two rows above it are blank).

I have tried [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116781/google-sheets-queryimportrange-with-named-range), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077747/how-to-select-a-named-range-in-google-sheets-query) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729251/google-sheets-import-range-within-a-query) to no avail.

**Problem**

I don't want the header included. I tried relabelling it using the label function in query according to the required order. If this does not work, how do I retrieve the data without the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "NamedRange"), "offset 1", 0), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&B2&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you for responding :). It works! Though not quite sure what the B2 stands for. Could you please explain?

Comment: There is an issue, when I insert data to the left of it (a column next to it), it does not return all the figures. It returns less than is in the original sheet. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: So it seems like just having the first line is more than enough to do that task. Thank you :)

Comment: @Desmond B2 is just an example

Comment: Linking docs for reference - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#offset